# Using the result of a query as a parameter for another query

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to use a query result as a parameter for another query.

As below:

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT mydate INTO : varmydate FROM work.MyTable WHERE codigo = 1234;
QUIT;
 
PROC SQL;
    SELECT * FROM work.MyOtherTable
    WHERE codata = &varmydate;
QUIT;
```

But, unfortunately, this didn't work.

In this example, the *varmydate* variable will receive a value of type data in the first query.

```
 96         PROC SQL;
 97             SELECT codata FORMAT date9., valor FROM work.MyOtherTable WHERE codata = &varmydate;
 NOTE: PROC SQL set option NOEXEC and will continue to check the syntax of statements.
 NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "VARMYDATE".
 97          01MAR2020
               _______
               22
               76
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, AND, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, 
               GROUP, GT, GTT, HAVING, LE, LET, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ORDER, ^=, |, ||, ~=.  
  ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
  98         QUIT;
```

After executing the first query, the command below:

```
%PUT &varmydate;
```

will have the following result:

01MAR2020

But the second query returns an error.

If I use the syntax below:

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT * FROM work.MyOtherTable
    WHERE codata = '01MAR2020'd;
QUIT;
```

then it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not indicate what the LOG window messaged regarding *didn't work*

I presume column `mydate` in table `mytable` is type character storing the date9. represention of a date.  *If it had instead been numeric variable with a date format the macro variable **myvardate** would have a value such as `21975`*

Thus, you need to resolve the date9 representation in a SAS date literal context

```
    WHERE codata = "&myvardate"d;
```

Double quotes are needed because macro resolution will not occur within single quoted literals.

Comment: The table was imported from excel.  The second query works using double quotes.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use INPUT function to convert de macro variável myvardate to number. If the query work when you use '01MAR2020'd probably the column codata has the type number.

Comment: Try the code below:

WHERE codata=input("&varmydate", date9.)